# When making a pandas comparison how to, return np.nan from np.nan>np.nan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, nan

I have the following two dataFrames:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2, 3],[4,3,6], [np.nan, 2, np.nan]])
     0  1    2
0  1.0  2  3.0
1  4.0  3  6.0
2  NaN  2  NaN
```

and

```
b = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,3],[5,3,5 ],[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])
     0    1    2
0  0.0  1.0  3.0
1  5.0  3.0  5.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

A comparison of a>b results in:

```
       0      1      2
0   True   True  False
1  False  False   True
2  False  False  False
```

I want however, that the output looks like:

```
     0      1      2
0   True   True  False
1  False  False   True
2   nan    nan     nan
```

The comparisons of `2>np.nan` and `np.nan>np.nan` should both result in `np.nan`. (or any other random value, that is different from True and False)

Anything will help!

Comment: But in the case that column will not be of the type `bool`? Is that okay with you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need adding a `mask`

```
yourdf=a.gt(b).mask(a.isna()|b.isna(),'nan')
Out[153]: 
       0      1      2
0   True   True  False
1  False  False   True
2    nan    nan    nan
```

Comment: Just pointing out that this could still be written with `a > b`, but will require parentheses (and some linters are not going to like it): `(a > b).mask(a.isna() | b.isna(), 'nan')`